Crypto.SE, Cryptocurrencies, and Close Reasons: The Way Forward
So, we recently got an answer from Catija the CM on our request for a fourth close reason.
The answer (and related mod-only discussions) boil down to the following:

We can get our fourth close reason, our case is good enough
We need to provide the initial formulation in the new five-part audience-specific style
We should consider proactive measures to reduce the amount of cryptocurrency questions

While we're at it, we might as well also convert and refine our existing close reasons to the new presentation format. Based on this, I have worked out the following schedule on how and when we discuss each issue:

Formulate our Cryptocurrency close-reason (this seems to have largely found consensus but is still open to further discussion / refinement)
Discuss if and how we want the sidebar to be adapted (we are here right now until at least the 25th of April)
Discuss if and how we want the new asker modal dialog to be adapted
Work out the audience-specific Ciphertext analysis close reason (we are also here until at least the 10th of July)
Work out the audience-specific Homework close reason
Work out the audience-specific Programming close reason

Each of these will get at least a week in the spotlight so everyone has a fair chance to participate.

I have temporarily un-featured this post so the close-vote threshold lowering request gets the attention instead.
